What would vehicles look like for aquatic species?
My setting is preindustrial, and the majority of the species are aquatic (nereids, naiads, merfolk, cephali, dryads, and most recently the Sunken People).
While humans are the main shipwrights of the setting, the aquatic species are still going to want their own vehicles. What would those look like?
Using a sail or kite underwater would obviously let you move in one direction. By varying lift forces (sail/kite parallel to current to act like an airfoil) and drag forces (some on the sail/kite, mostly on the main vessel, perhaps with fins) would you be able to steer? Ocean currents are much slower than winds, so this would only be viable for slow transports, if at all.
Alternatively, could underwater gliders be scaled up enough for carrying cargo or people?
Or would pure muscle power, either powering devices like corkscrew engines or just plain swimming, be most efficient?

Seems very broad, also multiple questions. Can you pare it down to one? (Without two media eg. air and water, there's nothing to lever against for steering like a keel with sail can in a boat - but different currents at different depths). Could you tell us what sort of thing you're expecting them to do with the transport, how far they go and how big?

@Escapeddentalpatient. I'll think about how to narrow the question down. In the meantime, it's not quite true that there's nothing to lever against in a single medium. Drag force and lift force are perpendicular to each other; if you used one for propulsion, you could use the other for leverage. Would that be enough to meaningfully steer in water? I have no idea, hence the question.

Consider the Nereids, those slippery sirens of the sea. Do they need vehicles? They are vehicles! Sleek, self-propelled, and equipped with built-in sonar far superior to anything those landlubber humans could cobble together. A Nereid's idea of a traffic jam is probably two other Nereids trying to flirt with the same merman.
Now, the Naiads, bless their dripping souls, are a different kettle of fish altogether. Utterly obsessed with comfort and aesthetics, their vehicles would undoubtedly resemble elaborate underwater gazebos, propelled by trained schools of bioluminescent jellyfish. Think of it: a leisurely drift through the coral gardens, sipping kelp tea and gossiping about the latest seahorse fashions. Practical? Hardly. Stylish? Indubitably.
The Merfolk, ah, the Merfolk. Always trying to imitate humans, aren't they? You'll find them desperately attempting to adapt human technologies, resulting in contraptions like the "Sea-Cycle," a bicycle with kelp tires that invariably gets tangled in seaweed. Or the "Submarine Chariot," a glorified bathtub pulled by disgruntled sea turtles. The ultimate irony, of course, is that they already have tails perfectly designed for swimming.
The Cephali, on the other tentacle, are far more pragmatic. Jet propulsion, my friend, is the Cephali way. Imagine sleek, streamlined pods zipping through the ocean depths, powered by carefully controlled bursts of ink. The only downside is the perpetual cloud of squid ink that hangs over their cities, making everything look like a badly written gothic novel.
The Dryads, being essentially amphibious trees, are a bit of a puzzle. Do they even want to move? Perhaps they simply extend their roots across the seabed, forming a sort of living, underwater railway network. Or maybe they just hitch a ride on a passing whale. Who knows with Dryads? They're a mysterious bunch.
And finally, the Sunken People. Poor sods. They're still trying to figure out how to dry their socks underwater, let alone develop advanced transportation. You'll likely find them paddling around in leaky rowboats, complaining about the dampness and longing for the good old days when they lived on land. Someone should really tell them about waterproof sealant. Or maybe not. It's more amusing this way.

While this does not answer the practical concerns of the question, from a world building perspective it is a great answer.  Having 6 different races, each with their own flavor or transportation will be a good way to make each civilization feel uniquely them.

? You can perfectly sail against the wind, you are just crossing the wind from time to time, in a sort of zig-zag pattern.
So i imagine you would have local propulsion (mechanical, chemical, biological whatever) - and then you have a sort of highway system, where local propulsion capsules snatch a ride on a catamaran.
If they are fancy they would actually go - into a "spaceship", as in - a water-filled sailboat, driven by watery creatures in dive-suits.
One can imagine this as a hydro-foiling-katamaran, almost flying over the waves, releasing small water vehicles and cargo at the destination. It would be the trans-orbital flight of their world.
Below the sea, the fastest one can go- would be a cavitation torpedo.

Don't they have sea animal pulled vehicles in like Aquaman and stuff?
Probably makes the most sense because other than that there isn't much else to use besides muscle power from underwater people like on a galley if the technology isn't that advanced.
Maybe they use underwater currents like the Gulf Stream but I doubt these can be used as easily as wind because I don't think they change nearly as much as wind.
The might be used for something like an underwater bus route that always moves the same way in the same direction, going in circles but probably wouldn't be useful if you wanted to use a vehicle to a specific place not on that route and you'd still have to take a different vehicle to avoid having to swim yourself for hours.
Also, the idea that just because some species can easily move in an environment humans need vehicles for to move easily, e.g. flight or extended underwater swimming, makes no sense because cars and trains do exist and are quite popular.
Why walk 30 minutes when you need 5 minutes with the subway? Some may want the exercise but obviously 95% don't.
So, why swim yourself and tire out your fin muscles when you can just take an underwater vehicle?
